# Adding attributes and values from another model via sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Im using sequelize i want that my result (JSON) looks like that (see: WantResult). is it possible to get back exactly that JSON by modifing my function?

Here is my function:

```
try {
          const mediImport = await User.findOne({

            where: { Id: 1 },
            // Select forename as Vorname, name as Nachname
            attributes: [['forename', 'Vorname'], ['name', 'Nachname']],
            include: {
              model: SurveyResult,
              attributes: ['result', 'result'] }

          })
```

Here is my result:

```
    {
    "Person": {
        "Vorname": "Mustermann",
        "Nachname": "Max",
        "SurveyResult": {
            "result": {
                "birthdate": "01.01.1990",
                "Sind Sie miteinander verheiratet?": "Ja",
                "Waren Sie wegen Ihres Kinderwunsches bereits in ärztlicher Behandlung?": "Ja"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WantResult: But i want that my result looks like that

```
Person": {
        "Vorname": "Mustermann",
        "Nachname": "Max",
        "birthdate": "01.01.1990"
```

Comment: try this : `attributes: [['forename', 'Vorname'], ['name', 'Nachname'] , ['SurveyResult.result.birthdate' , 'birthdate']],`

Comment: that didnt work. The SurveyResult is another model. im getting this error: 'Unknown column \'SurveyResult.result.birthdate\' in \'field list\'',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like this (This works in the case that `birthday` is an attribute from `SurveyResult` and is not inside `result`)  :

```
try {
  const mediImport = await User.findOne({

    where: { Id: 1 },
    // Select forename as Vorname, name as Nachname
    attributes: [
        ['forename', 'Vorname'], 
        ['name', 'Nachname'],
        [sequelize.literal('"SurveyResult"."birthdate"'), 'birthdate']
    ],
    include: {
        model: SurveyResult,
        attributes: [] 
    }
  })
}
```